# How to find first and last characters in a file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on this revision exercise which asks to copy an input file to an output file and return the first and last letters.

[image]

```
def copy_file(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, "r")
    content = input_file.read()
    content[0]
    content[1]
    return content[0] + content[-1]
    

    input_file.close()
```

Why do I get an error message which I try get the first and last letters? And how would I copy the file to the output file?

Here is the test:

```
input_f = "FreeAdvice.txt"
first_last_chars = copy_file(input_f)
print(first_last_chars)
print_content('cure737.txt')
```

Error Message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hjac737(my username).txt'
```

Comment: "Why do I get an error message" - what _is_ the error message?

Comment: I don't see `'hjac737(my username).txt'` in your code.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't mention a file called `'hjac737(my username).txt'`. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

All the code after a `return` statement is never executed, a proper code editor would highlight it to you, so I recommend you use one. So the file was never closed. A good practice is to use a **context manager** for that : it will automatically call `close` for you, even in case of an exception, when you exit the scope (indentation level).

The code you provided also miss to write the file content, which may be causing the error you reported.

I explicitely used the `"rt"` (and `"wt"`) mode for the files (althought they are defaults), because we want the first and last character of the file, so it supports Unicode (any character, not just ASCII).

```
def copy_file(filename):

    with open(filename, "rt") as input_file:
        content = input_file.read()
    print(input_file.closed)  # True

    my_username = "LENORMJU"
    output_file_name = my_username + ".txt"
    with open(output_file_name, "wt") as output_file:
        output_file.write(content)
    print(output_file.closed)  # True

    # last: return the result
    return content[0] + content[-1]

print(copy_file("so67730842.py"))
```

When I run this script (on itself), the file is copied and I get the output `d)` which is correct.